# Using javascript to print images

Tags: javascript, image, popup, printing

I would like to know if it's possible to use javascript to open a popup window containing an image, and at the same time have the print dialog show. Once someone clicks on print, the popup closes.

Is this easily attainable?

Answer (score 31):

Another great solution!! All credit goes to Codescratcher

```
<script>

    function ImageToPrint(source)
    {
        return "<html><head><scri"+"pt>function step1(){\n" +
                "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" +
                "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" +
                "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" +
                "<img src='" + source + "' /></body></html>";
    }
    
    function PrintImage(source)
    {
        var Pagelink = "about:blank";
        var pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");
        pwa.document.open();
        pwa.document.write(ImageToPrint(source));
        pwa.document.close();
    }

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="PrintImage('YOUR_IMAGE_PATH_HERE.JPG'); return false;">PRINT</a>
```

See the full example [here](http://www.codescratcher.com/javascript/print-image-using-javascript/#comment-762).

Comment: why is there a 10 ms timeout? Why not simply `<img onload='step2()'>`

Comment: That codescratcher site is a little confusing I uploaded this code to my github account: See working demo here https://rawgit.com/orellabac/printFromJavascript/master/Print_Image.htm code is at: https://github.com/orellabac/printFromJavascript/

Comment: Updated: `function printImage(source) {
 var pwa = window.open(source, "_new")
 pwa.document.open()
 pwa.document.write("<html><head><scri"+"pt>function step1(){\n" + "setTimeout('step2()', 10);}\n" + "function step2(){window.print();window.close()}\n" + "</scri" + "pt></head><body onload='step1()'>\n" + "<img src='" + source + "' /></body></html>")
 pwa.document.close()
}`

Comment: @RixTheTyrunt What if I have multiple images (N) to print ? How do I await every single one of them to load ? How to prepare them for print ?

Comment: Good question tho ツ

Comment: Thank you so much! after all solution. this worked

Answer (score 25):

```
popup = window.open();
popup.document.write("imagehtml");
popup.focus(); //required for IE
popup.print();
```

Comment: How would this work using a button? The button would initiate this action, but actually prints a separate image.

Comment: I'm not going to write all the code for you, the point of this place is to learn. ;)
You'd do it using the onmouseup event on the button:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp

Comment: I don't want you to write it for me... just want to be pointed to the right resources. I need a place to start. Thanks.

Comment: Found fix for IE: before `popup.print();` you need to call `popup.focus();`

Answer (score 10):

Use this in the head block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printImg() {
  pwin = window.open(document.getElementById("mainImg").src,"_blank");
  pwin.onload = function () {window.print();}
}
</script>
```

use this in the body block

```
<img src="images.jpg" id="mainImg" />
<input type="button" value="Print Image"  onclick="printImg()" />
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. However it worked well using php server but when I moved to lighttpd it did not print the image alone but the page where it came from. Still looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 6):

A cross browser solution `printImage(document.getElementById('buzzBarcode').src)`

```js
/**
 * Prints an image by temporarily opening a popup
 * @param {string} src - image source to load
 * @returns {void}
 */
function printImage(src) {
    var win = window.open('about:blank', "_new");
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write([
        '<html>',
        '   <head>',
        '   </head>',
        '   <body onload="window.print()" onafterprint="window.close()">',
        '       <img src="' + src + '"/>',
        '   </body>',
        '</html>'
    ].join(''));
    win.document.close();
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

button {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<img id="buzzBarcode" src="https://barcode.orcascan.com/qrcode/buzz.png?text=to infinity and beyond" width="150" height="150" />
```

Comment: I had to add `style="margin: 0"` on the body tag to avoid having an empty first page when printing.

Answer (score 5):

This code will open YOUR_IMAGE_URL in a popup window, show print dialog and close popup window after print.

```
var popup;

function closePrint () {
    if ( popup ) {
        popup.close();
    }
}

popup = window.open( YOUR_IMAGE_URL );
popup.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
popup.onafterprint = closePrint;
popup.focus(); // Required for IE
popup.print();
```

[MDN Reference code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing#Print_an_external_page_without_opening_it)

Answer (score 1):

Yea, just put the image on the screen, and then call `window.print();` in javascript and it should popup.

(This is how Google Maps/Google Calendar do printing)

Comment: Cool. But what if I want a different image to show that initiates the popup window?

Comment: Check out the CSS styles for printing. You can basically have an image hidden on the screen view, and then visible for the print view.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome:

```
  <body ><img  src="image.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function() {
                    window.print();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.close();
                    }, 1);
                };
            </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 45 minutes on this "SIMPLE" problem, trying to get it the way I wanted it to operate.

I had an image inside an img tag, dynamically generated by a `jQuery Barcode` plugin that I had to print. I wanted it to print in another window and afterwards close the window. This was all supposed to happen after the user clicked a button inside a `jQuery Grid` plugin, inside a `jQuery-UI` dialog along with `jQuery-UI` dialog extender applied to it.

I adjusted everyone answers till I finally came up with this, maybe it can help someone.

```
w = window.open(document.getElementById("UB-canvas").src);
w.onload = function () { w.print(); }
w.onbeforeunload = setTimeout(function () { w.close(); },500);
w.onafterprint = setTimeout(function () { w.close(); },500);
```

The `setTimeout` is not just for shits and giggles, it's the only way I found `Firefox 42` would hit those functions. It would just simply skip the `.close()` functions until I added a breakpoint to it, then it worked perfectly. So I'm assuming it created those window instances before it could apply the onbeforeload event function and onafterprint event functions, or something.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a coffee script function that does that (but without opening a new window):

```
@print_img = (url) ->
$children = $('body').children().hide()
$img = $('<img>', src: url)
$img.appendTo('body')

$img.on 'load', ->
  window.print()
  $(this).remove()
  $children.show()
```

Or if you prefer in javascript:

```
this.print_img = function(url) {
  var $children, $img;
  $children = $('body').children().hide();
  $img = $('<img>', {
    src: url
  });
  $img.appendTo('body');

  $img.on('load', function() {
    window.print();
    $(this).remove();
    $children.show();
  });
};
```

This function makes sure that the elements on the body are hidden and not redrawn into the DOM.
It also makes sure that the image is loaded before calling print (if the image is too large and the internet connection is slow, it may take a while to load the img, if you call print too soon, it will print an empty page)