# how to print multiple images with aspecific size in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

i have agridview show issues every row show issue and template field called print 
when i press print i want to loop into database and get all documents (as images) belongs to this issues and print it in fixed size (print paper size)

i use this code

```
      PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
             if (Images.Count >0)
             {
                 foreach (string file in Images)
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         filename = file;
                         if (!File.Exists(filename))
                         {
                             throw new FileNotFoundException();
                         }

                         pd.PrintPage += Doc_PrintPage;

                         pd.Print();
                     }
                     catch (Exception exce)
                     { MessageBox.Show(exce.Message.ToString()); }

                 }

             }


   private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
       System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, 0, 0);
    }
```

but print dialogue not appear and printed document not fit paper of print
how i can i do this function

Comment: This is a matter of client/server difference. If you run server code, it will run on the server, hence print ON THE SERVER , not at the client...

Comment: no i want it as a client side

Comment: So obviously you shouldn't use server code to do it... You'd probably achieve what you want with a print CSS and javascript's print() function, but that you've got to look into and come back with a specific problem

Comment: Dear user1637402,what user Bartdude said is 100% correct.
You are missing some basic web application principles, please allow me to clarify.
The code you provided executes on the web server, not on the end user computer where the browser runs, so you have to get your date from the database and convert it into something your client browser computer downlaods and shows to the user>

Comment: ok thanks 4 explain but really i want to run aserver code to get all images right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use javascript (or something similar ex. jQuery) to print out the images on the browser. You cannot interact directly with a users computer through ASP.NET.

ASP.NET is a server-side language.

The only language that is actually capable of both server-side and client-side is Java since you could have a Java application to interact with a users computer, however I do not recommend this.

There is a reason why you cannot directly interact with a users computer from your webserver and it's simply for security reasons. If it was possible to do so then anyone could setup a webserver and basically just screw over anyone visiting.

I would take a look at this:
[Using javascript to print images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909033/using-javascript-to-print-images)

Comment: ok but how can i pass images from database to javascript ?

Comment: plz i need help in it any one can help me  ?

Comment: any one know how to get all images from database and pass it to javascript and print all images by it's link ?