# Unable to load image in multiple window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have issue in print receipt with image in for loop when i am using below code
**it doesn't load image when multiple print using for loop** (It is working fine single print) but i have remove image reference it is work fine.
So, Please give me solution.

```
 function printReceipt() {

        for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {

            var imageData = '<img src="./images/image.png"/>';

            var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');
            newWin.document.open();
            newWin.document.write('<html><title>WEB</title><body onload="window.print()">' + imageData + '</body></html>');
            newWin.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                newWin.close();
            }, 200);
        }
    }

    printReceipt();
```

Comment: Is the path correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct path in my code.

Comment: This might help you-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window

Answer (score 0):

check this link it may help you : 
[Help Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909033/using-javascript-to-print-images)

try to give alt attribute if image not found for that there may be a chance your URL is not correct :  
`var imageData = '<img src="./images/image.png" alt="Smiley face" />';`

Comment: then check  the link  i provided you