# How to print image inside in the html div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to print the image inside the HTML div tag. 
Here is my code:

HTML5:

```
<span>
      <img src="/images/pag.jpg" alt="pagsanghan Logo" style="opacity: .8; height:100px; width:100px;">
</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    function printDiv() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById("monthly-report");
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue you face with this code?

Comment: The image does not load to print preview

Comment: Sir, please give me some sample code.

Comment: You can search for something like using javascript to print images, or something like that on the internet, it will help you ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using javascript to print images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909033/using-javascript-to-print-images)

Answer (score 3):

you need to first convert your image to `base64` image. and add that code in src of the img tag. then the print function will print the image

convert your image to base64 in this [link](https://www.base64-image.de/)

```js
window.print();
```

```css
@media print {
    #monthly-report {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="monthly-report">
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="pagsanghan Logo" style="opacity: .8; height:100px; width:100px;">
</span>
```