# Print functionality is working on document load not on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one print button & on click of that button I want to print other pdf as per the link will provide not the same page. but for now print functionality is working on page load not on button click

```
function print (doc) {
var objFra = document.createElement('iframe');
objFra.style.visibility = 'hidden';
objFra.src = doc;
document.body.appendChild(objFra);
objFra.contentWindow.focus();
objFra.contentWindow.print();
}
print();

<input type="button" id="bt" onClick="print()" value="Print PDF"/>
```

Comment: remove `print();` and provide doc file path in `onClick`. check here: `onClick="print(<provide doc file path>)"`

Comment: Its not working, pdf is still opening on page load not on click button.

Comment: May be helpful:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909033/using-javascript-to-print-images

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` method is getting invoked on button click, but since it's visibility is set to hidden, it is not visible. You also have `print` method invoked on the page load.

```js
function print (doc) {
    var objFra = document.createElement('iframe');
    //objFra.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    objFra.src = doc;
    document.body.appendChild(objFra);
    objFra.contentWindow.focus();
    objFra.contentWindow.print();
}
print('path');
```

```html
<input type="button" id="bt" onClick="print('somePath')" value="Print PDF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call your print function on `$(document).ready(function(){})` function.